# Facebook - How to post feed on company page using custom name

Tags: facebook, posting

I am able to successfully post content to Company Page using the Facebook Graph API.

I have a query to know how to pass Personal Name or Company Name while posting the content.

I am referring to URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/ to post the content but didnt find out parameter for passing Personal Name/Company Name.

Please reply me as soon as possible.

Thanks,
Chirag

Comment: What exactly you mean by "pass Personal Name or Company Name"

Comment: Do you mean as the name of the user/page that the post was made by? You can not just pass any arbitrary name for that – it _is_ the name of the user or page that the post was made by (or on the behalf of).